# Mean Cauchy sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. A sequence of functions $f_n \in L^1 (X)$ is said to be *Cauchy in mean* if

$$\lim_{K \to \infty} \limsup_{N, M \to \infty} \frac{1}{NM} \sum_{i = K+1}^{K + N} \sum_{j = K+1}^{K + M} \|f_i - f_j\|_{L^1} = 0.$$

**Question:** Suppose $f_n$ are Cauchy in mean. Does there exist an $L^1$ convergent subsequence?

Comment: Maybe combine [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2529141/916889) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538928/916889)?